# Angular2/4 http POST services call .Net/MVC Web API 2.0 REST parameter is null

Tags: c#, .net, angular, rest

I have a .Net/C# Web API 2.0 REST service which works fine if test with Postman, but always get null parameter if call from Angular2/4 http service with Post.

below is the code:

```
C#:

public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // POST: api/users/login
    public string login([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var ss = value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Angular2 service:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    const headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const theBody = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    const requestoptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: this.host + '/users/login',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(theBody)
    })

    return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json;
        })
        .catch(this.logAndPassOn);
}
```

When test with Postman, I set header as Content-Type : application/json, and body select "raw".

everything looks the same, however the Angular2 Http Post service doesn't work anyway, I always get null value.

Thanks in advance for any any help.

Comment: you get null in component or service have you subscribed in the component ?

Comment: Do you use `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: thank you for your quick response. the JSON in raw body is: "{'email': email, 'password': password}"

Comment: the null is in servie   public string login([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var ss = value;
        return value;
    }  the call comes in successful, just value is null.

Comment: I tried with or without [HttpPost], it is the same.

Comment: yeap, instead of use `JSON.stringify(theBody)`, you try to use only `theBody`

Comment: I tried without JSON.stringify use theBody only actually though I believe it should be JSON.stringify(), the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `JSON.stringify`: There's no need to convert it to a string.

On the Web Api side, you'll be better off with a POCO for the incoming data. Create a class that includes two string properties, e.g.:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then, change `[FromBody]string value` to `[FromBody]LoginViewModel viewModel`.

To try and clarify a little more, there's a big difference between this:

```
{
    "email": "some-email",
    "password": "some-password"
}
```

and this:

```
"{ email: 'some-email', password: 'some-password' }"
```

The first example is a JSON object, whereas the second is just a string and nothing more. It doesn't matter that the data inside looks like JSON: it isn't. In your Postman example, you were actually sending a string, but perhaps Angular is being a bit clever and basically ignoring your `JSON.stringify` in the first place.

Comment: YES! remove JSON.stringify and use  [FromBody]LoginViewModel viewModel works! but I got confused, I set 'Content-Type' as 'application/json', it should be json string?

Can you explain what's the reason?

Comment: `application/json` is for describing a raw JSON object, not a JSON object serialized into a string. If you really did want a string to be passed through, you'd want to try going for `text/plain`, but I wouldn't recommend this. Do you really need it to be a string rather than a real object?

Comment: I double tried if only service side use LoginViewModel, no matter with or without JSON.stringify() at client side, it works fine, I never realized it could be this way, learned now.